# Entity Framework Code First - Interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface, ef-code-first, code-first

I would like to make app for restaurant. It´s about calculation recipes.

I have domain classes:
- Ingredient
- Recipe
- RecipeItem

Recipe has List of RecipeItem.

RecipeItem could be Ingredient but also Recipe.

So I'm using Interface IItem with 2 properties(Id, Name). 
If I use Interface in my class, db generator ignore this field.

Look at my classes here:

```
public class Ingredient : IItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }

public class Recipe : IItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<RecipeItem> RecipeItems { get; set; }
    }

public class RecipeItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IItem Item { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

CodeFirst automaticly generate for me database with tables above.

I would like to have database table RecipeItem looks likes:

```
> Id 
> Quantity 
> Recipe_Id - FK of Recipe ID 
> RecipePointer - Nullable FK of specific Recipe
> IngredientPointer - Nullable FK of specific Ingredient
```

But there are only:

```
> Id 
> Quantity 
> Recipe_Id - FK of Recipe ID
```

If I put into RecipeItem for example Ingredient, than Id of Ingredient will be inserted to IngredientPointer.

I would like to use FLUENT API for mapping but I don't know how.

I don't know if is possible what I want, or if is any better way how to solve my problem.

I watched already CodeFirst video on Pluralsight and I browse in forums but I can't find answer.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it can be done, but if it can, do not use an interface but a class, please try

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient : Item
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe : Item
{
    public List<RecipeItem> RecipeItems { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Then you may want to read about [EF and TPH](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the DataAnnotations to clarify it for EF how to generate the DB Generation Script

for your solution i can propose you

use the InversProperty and ForeignKey Attributes

have a look at the following resources :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx